# How to increase the security of One-Time Pad algorithm?

Tags: one-time-pad

Is there any ways to increase the security of One Time Pad algorithm?
We required to make a write up on how to increase the security of classical cryptography algorithm. In this case, we are choosing one-time pad.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. By definition, the key of a one-time pad is random and as long as the message, so these requirements are automatically fulfilled. Maybe instead of a one-time pad, you mean something else. Then you should clarify this in your posting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is obviously based on a wrong understanding how the one time pad algorithm works. This is clear from suggested "improvements" like ensuring the key is random (otherwise it would not be OTP) and "longer key" (the key is already as long as the message).

Comment: Please clarify of you really meant One-Time Pad because the question makes no sense and it is possible that you are confusing different concepts with each other.

Comment: If you are confirming that that is a One-Time Pad, then this question still makes little sense. And, you have not shown your work for how you would answer this question. We can't do your homework for you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you need to show how you would answer the homework question.

Comment: Historically, one time pads have been broken, but only when a) the key was reused (i.e., not a one time pad) or b) the key was compromised by typically some physical means, such as the code book being stolen.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you wish to increase the security of one time pad? It is already THE most secure algorithm; it cannot be broken. It is far more secure than whatever hash functions you might wish to use.

But that is only so if you implement one time pad correctly. Absolute prerequisites for the security of a one time pad scheme, among others, are that the key must be fully random and that its length must be equal to the length of the message.

Therefore, I am sorry to say, but wondering if we can improve one time pad by increasing the length of the key or making it more random seems to me to show a fundamental lack of understanding of how one time pad works and how to implement it.